# Can't view the different file types in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am taking file input from the user(any file type). I want them to view If it is an Image or else a download link. How can I do this?

Comment: On your file record get the file extension by explode() and play with extension as your exoectation

Comment: If my file contains spaces It will create problems. So I am appending timestamp at end of the file and using preg_replace to get the spaces removed from the file name. Then I can use explode and It will work.

Comment: I have posted the  answer and If anyone can provide an efficient laravel way to do so I will be really glad

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So In my blade file, I did this by getting a query object and comparing the image types supported by browsers

```
 @if(strtolower(File::extension($book->filename))=='jpg'|| 
                    strtolower(File::extension($book->filename))=='bmp' ||
                     strtolower(File::extension($book->filename))=='png' ||
                      strtolower(File::extension($book->filename))=='gif' ||
                       strtolower(File::extension($book->filename))=='svg' ||
                        strtolower(File::extension($book->filename))=='apng' ||
                         strtolower(File::extension($book->filename))=='bmp ico'||
                          strtolower(File::extension($book->filename))=='png ico')<img src="{{  asset("uploads/$book->filename") }} "height="113px" width="96px" />@else<a href="{{('uploads/'.$book->filename)}}" target="_blank"><button>Click here to download file</button></a>
                          @endif
```

This looks very heavy but getting image type is far easier then checking for all types that can be uploaded by the browser. So I extracted them and rest things will come in form of a downloadable link. Also, use `use Response;` and `use File;` . It will work smoothly.

Comment: `in_array(strtolower(File::extension($book->filename)), ['jpg', 'bmp', 'png', 'gif', 'svg', 'apgn', 'bmp ico', 'png ico'])`

Comment: I would recommend you to use mimeType instead of file extension.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/7517/what-is-the-relationship-between-mime-types-and-file-extensions

Answer (score 3):

Figure out the mime type of the file in question and determine the following action based on that.

API Reference:
https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_mimeType

Comment: That is very complex and Laravel provides some excellent features for it. I found my answer and I will post here. It's really great to get a response so soon.